# Logstash in ECS with cloudwatch plugin keeps crashing. Why is it throwing this error?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, logstash-configuration, opensearch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

So I added the following inputs to my logstash configuration so we can start ingesting cloud watch metrics

```
input {
    cloudwatch {
        namespace => "AWS/Logs"
        metrics => [ "IncomingBytes", "IncomingLogEvents" ]
        filters => { "LogGroupName" => "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/bird-nest-api-dev/var/log/nginx/access.log" }
        region => "us-west-2"
    }
}

input {
    cloudwatch {
        namespace => "AWS/Logs"
        metrics => [ "IncomingBytes", "IncomingLogEvents" ]
        filters => { "LogGroupName" => "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/bird-nest-api-prod/var/log/nginx/error.log" }
        region => "us-west-2"
    }
}
```

And now it is throwing this error.

Exception: RuntimeError

```
Stack: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-integration-aws-7.0.0/lib/logstash/inputs/cloudwatch.rb:154:in `run'

/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:410:in `inputworker'

/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:401:in `block in start_input'
```

When I run the same docker container image locally though with the same logstash config it works just fine. I am using the same access key and secret when I run it locally as my ecs stack should be using.

I've downloaded the same image tag deployed on ECS to run locally and it runs just fine. It's outputting the metrics to open search directly as it should. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY were not being set correctly in the service configuration. Not that you would guess that at all from the error.